# laravel on apache vs php artisan serve

Tags: apache, laravel

When running test php file on **apache** server, with the following route:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $name='some_name';
    return View::make('index')->with('name',$name);
});
```

And my view code is simple:

```
<?= $name ?>
```

Or with blade:

```
{{ $name }}
```

I get no variable **$name** on the screen, when I open index.php file. But when I run this with **php artisan serve** of built in **php -S server**  there is a content of variable on the page.I suppose it is something with apache settings. 
There is no **error logs** in apache log file.

Can someone help.

Comment: Can you check error logs on Apache? Perhaps its hiding errors from you? Do you get other output from the view? Can you show view code? There are quite a few possible reasons.

Comment: Is apache set up to go to laravels public directory?

Comment: try `<?php echo $name ?>` in case php has short tags turned off in the `php.ini` file used with Apache. What environment is apache being run in? Virtual machine? a real server? MAMP, WAMP?

Answer (score 1):

There was more than one problem:

First I had to enable mcrypt extension in */etc/php5/apache2/php.ini* with:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

And in */etc/php5/cli/php.ini*

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Second part of problem was to enable all permissions on *app/storage/**

Now everything works great.